# html.beginform v old skool form tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, forms

What is the benefit to using Html.BeginForm?

We're having some issues related to html helpers and razor generator view testing and I'm struggling to see the benefit which would stop us going back to old skool form tags.

Has anyone got an argument for or against either?

by old skool i mean:

```
<form action="@Url.Action('Blah')">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Html.BeginForm` is useful because it generates the url using the routes defined in the Global.asax. (or you can extend it with your own code)

Using the old tag is neither worst or best in my opinion. You simply have to generate your url manually or using the Url helper. In the end the html in the page will be the same

```
<form ....>

   html

</form>
```

Comment: In fact that's what I mean when I say "use Url helper" :)

Comment: gonna mark this one as correct as it was 1st in. It's clear there is no real reason to use the beginform stuff. it's been a good example of using IDisposable for other stuff in our project but for this particular case we're gonna drop it in favor of testability.

Answer (score 2):

`Html.BeginForm` also implements `IDisposable`, meaning the form must be closed properly.  It's a minor thing, perhaps, but not closing `Html.BeginForm` produces a run-time error, where an unclosed `<form>` tag does not.

Comment: Probably worth adding: an unclosed form tag **does** throw a run-time error if it was opened inside another code block.

Answer (score 2):

no there is no difference , the form tag just use the routing to generate the url , so if you use `@Url.Action` you are good to go

there is even books use that way a plain old tag and a url helper to generate the route

`ASP.NET MVC Website Programming` is an example

---

### **Edit**

**
starting from Mvc 4 there is no difference , prior to Mvc 4 , Mvc 3 for example require the `Html.BeginForm` to make the javascript unobtrusive validation to work